# Azure Backup Retention strategy

Tags: azure, backup

I'm trying to wrap my head around Azure Backup retention points & want to know if the retention policy I'm choosing is optimal. With reference to the Azure pricing calculator, if I take 30 Daily RPs (Recovery Points) & 5 Yearly RPs, won't my VM data be adequately covered.

[screenshot from Azure pricing calculator about RPs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFOKE.jpg)

What will I miss if I ignore Weekly & Monthly RPs? What scenarios would need Weekly & Monthly RPs?

Answer (score 1):

If churn happens at a consistent rate daily, then having only daily is also fine
If you see some unexpected churn take an adhoc backup and then give higher retention for that, If you observe that churn is possible mostly during month ends (say for finance applications), then having a monthly point might make sense